# Animating a Nurbs Path's Influence

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

Say you have a spiralling object with an armature rig, which in turn has a Spline IK bone constraint to a nurbs path, as per [a tutorial for a bending phone cord](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLONnEcaHgQ).

Now you want to animate the various poses you've made by warping the nurbs path, such that you can import it into Unity.

I've tried adding LocRot keyframes of all the armature's bones in each pose, as well as "Object (or Pose)->Animation->Bake Action"; none of the armature's changes from the Nurbs path's influence come through in any Action clip. Ideally one would just animate the positions of the Nurbs path; alas, Blender doesn't let you add keyframes of individual vertices of anything in Edit Mode.

Some light to shed?

Comment: Every curve has Shape key options - animate the curve through shape keys and bake the animation of pose-bones for export into unity.

Comment: Perhaps convert the NURB to a verticed curve. Then create shape keys of the various desired poses and key framing their values would achieve your goal.

Comment: Actually, I just made a quick example with several shape keys of a default NURBScurve without converting to a meshed curve. Pose your NURB in object mode, click on the "data" tab for your curve, Shape Keys and press the Plus button to create a pose "Basis". Switch to Edit mode and reposition the Nurb control points as desired for your second pose. Switch back to object mode and press the "Plus" button to add your second pose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape key animation did it. For posterity, you hover over the value slider under the shape key list and hit "I" to insert a frame with that value.

Thanks Jerryno and user2511.